# Driving distance between two coordinates

Tags: macros, coordinates, driving-distance

I have a long list of locations in excel format and I need to calculate driving distance between these locations using lat&long. Is there any macro I can use.
Cheers

Answer (score 11):

from : [link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/202255-calculating-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points.html)
this is too simple

```
Miles:
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) + SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) * 
SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) * COS(RADIANS(Long1-Long2))) * 3959

Kilometers:
=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) + SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) * 
SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) * COS(RADIANS(Long1-Long2))) * 6371
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks