# How to Find Top 3 Nearest Location Given Lat Long in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I have 2 sheets in Excel named Sheet1 and Sheet2. The table structure simply like below:

Sheet1

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

I want to find 3 nearest location from Sheet1 to Sheet2. Example of expected output should be:

[image: Sheet1]

I already tried `=LOOKUP(1,1/FREQUENCY(0,MMULT((Sheet2!B$2:C$5-Sheet1!B2:C2)^2,{1;1})), Sheet2!A$2:A$5)` but it only gave me 1 nearest location only.

Excel version: Excel 365

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your excel version?

Comment: It will depend very much on the definition of the distance: are you using Pythagoras distance (sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2), Manhattan distance (abs(x2-x1) + abs(y2-y1)) or some other distance definition?

Comment: @Harun24hr I've edited my post, I am using Excel 365 version

Comment: @Dominique I simply use point to point distance, so it is straight line distance

Comment: Use vlookup, but have 3 versions changing the lookup parameter a small amount.

Comment: @SolarMike could you please give an example of it?

Comment: So why can't you come up with two other "lookup_values" adjusted for your definition of "nearest"?

Comment: Or consider controlling the data table to exclude the closest range of targets etc

Answer (score 2):

Right, at risk of having a faulty calculation of distance, try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=REDUCE("Nearest #"&{1,2,3},ROW(A2:A6),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TAKE(TOROW(SORTBY(A9:A13,ABS(INDEX(B:B,y)-B9:B13)+ABS(INDEX(C:C,y)-C9:C13))),,3))))
```

Using a calculated distance of `ABS(lat1-lat2)+ABS(long1-long2)` gave me the exact same results as trying to find the actual distance in, say miles, using other more intricate formulae like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52686350/9758194) one. Are you sure about your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

So an example of vlookup() being used to do a straight line interpolation between two X values to give the calculated Y value.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$A$5:$B$8,2,1)+((A2-(VLOOKUP(A2+5,$A$5:$B$8,1,1)-VLOOKUP(A2,$A$5:$B$8,1,1)))/(VLOOKUP(A2+5,$A$5:$B$8,1,1)-VLOOKUP(A2,$A$5:$B$8,1,1)))*(VLOOKUP(A2+5,$A$5:$B$8,2,1)-VLOOKUP(A2,$A$5:$B$8,2,1))
```

[image]

Used this to get temperatures, density etc from steam tables aka tables of the properties of water and air.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Pythagoras distance](https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/distance-between-two-points/) to calculate nearest location using SUMPRODUCT and INDEX.

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Notice I've added just a test column with `Alpacca` and a rank column just to check my output but you don't need them.

Array formula (you must introduce it pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,SUMPRODUCT(--(SMALL (SQRT (($B2-Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6)^2+($C2-Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6)^2), RIGHT (D$1,1))= SQRT (($B2-Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6)^2+($C2-Sheet2!$C$2:$C$6)^2))*ROW(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6))-1)
```

If, by any chance, 2 or more locations are **exactly** at the same distance, the formula won't work and will return wrong output.