# Calculate font height at different size, how to find find ratio?

Tags: math, font-size, proportions

I have following dimensions of font Verdana height i measured (measurements are taken by hand so might be not very precise, i need to figure out ratio):

```
600 - 635px
500 - 530px
400 - 424px
300 - 318px
200 - 212px
100 - 107px
75  - 85px 
50  - 54px 
40  - 43px 
30  - 33px 
20  - 22px 
10  - 11px
```

How do i figure out what what height in "px" will be at font size "size 70" or "size 160"?

Comment: Do an interpolation - a straight line would be the difference of px for the two values either side of target divided by the difference of size for the same points either side of target, then multiply by the amount above the lower so 70 - 50 is 20 in your case.

Comment: @SolarMike i am not sure what's interpolation is could you submit an answer with details? not a mathematical person

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "height"? E.g the height of a capital letter, maximum height (including ascenders and descenders)? You could retrieve the font's proportions using a parsing library like opentype.js

Answer (score 0):

So interpolation:

for the 70 target then:

for the x: 75 - 50 = 25

for the y: 85 - 54 = 31

Divide 31 by 25 is 1.24 which is the amount y changes when x changes by 1.

vlookup() can be used to get the nearest x's and y's and will be a good exercise.

So the result is 54 (value at 50) plus 1.24 * 20 = 24.8 ie 78.8.

Not going to repeat an answer so check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470021/4961700