# Converting irregularly time stamped measurements into equally spaced time series in excel

Tags: excel, time-series

Good morning

I have 3 sets of irregularly timestamped data for three different variables that I would like to transform to regularly spaced time data so that the data can be added and subtracted from each other. The data series include between 300 and 600 observations over 7 days for each series.

How can I use Excel to transform the data to true time series with reasonable (maybe 15 minute) equal time intervals?

The three series look like this when plotted using an Excel XY scatterplot that combines the three series.

[image: Updated irregular time-series]

*Removed missing data part of question as I solved this in a different way.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Laurens

Sample data:

Existing data sample:

```
Time  | Solar       | Wind         | Load       
----- | ----------- | ------------ | -----------
0.018 |             |              | 23.70282636
0.039 |             | -168.7847188 |            
0.048 |             |              | 23.50072404
0.077 |             |              | 23.31550898
0.093 |             | -164.5686453 |            
0.107 |             |              | 23.354731  
0.137 |             |              | 23.59986857
0.146 |             | -161.0646197 |            
0.166 |             |              | 24.42353083
0.182 |             |              | 25.45310866
0.193 |             | -157.9259872 |            
0.197 |             |              | 26.43978741
0.206 |             |              | 27.37498727
0.216 |             |              | 28.35880608
0.227 |             | -152.6355957 |            
0.268 |             | -149.0160186 |            
0.290 | 30.36385532 |              |            
0.293 |             | -149.8404255 |            
0.295 |             | -155.3494979 |            
0.300 | 23.66498298 |              |            
0.305 | 15.42021702 |              |            
0.310 | 7.690748936 |              |
```

Desired data:

```
Interval   | 0.0104 |      |     
---------- | ------ | ---- | ----
Time       | Solar  | Wind | Load
00000      | Y1     | Y2   | Y3  
0.0104etc. |        |      |     
0.0208     |        |      |     
0.0313     |        |      |     
0.0417     |        |      |     
0.0521     |        |      |     
0.0625     |        |      |     
0.0729     |        |      |     
0.833      |        |      |     
0.0938     |        |      |     
0.1042     |        |      |     
0.1146     |        |      |
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of your dataset: the raw data and how you would like it to be transformed?

Comment: Sure. I will add to original post

Comment: It doesn't seem necessary to make the data evenly spaced. Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: If this is truly an `x-y scatter plot` and you have selected the Time column for the x-axis, the time values will be spaced evenly. The fact that your x-axis shows serial integers suggests you are not using the proper type of graph or data sets to construct it.. For the `NA` you will need to alter your data to replace the data points you do not wish displayed with `=NA()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity    I don't need it to be evenly spaced for charting purposes but if I want to add or in any other way combine these data series I need them to be on the same X-axes.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it is a true x-y scatter plot but for the moment the X-axes is in days and decimal fractions of days. I take the point on the NA but my biggest problem is that I d don't have one X axis with multiple Y values for the different variables

Comment: @Laurens Not sure what you mean. Here is a [graph](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aml6o6HIc9uOyl5rGRxJAVS9sAVQ?e=eYGOnr) from the data you posted

Comment: @Laurens - You have missing data. How is that to be handled? Knowing how to handle that and what the other data means is important.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have now fixed the "missing data" - I assume you referred to the gaps in the solar data. I don't know how to post the updated data neatly.

Comment: @Laurens - No, I meant that there is no data after 0.216 for Load and no data before 0.290 for Solar. How are we meant to handle that data?

Comment: So interpolation between two points, edit to suit your application: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470021/4961700

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how accurate the results need to be, but you could try rounding your time data, then take the mean values if needed.

15 minutes corresponds to ~0.01 (= 15 / (24 * 60)) in Excel. If your time data was in column A, column B could be `=ROUND(A1/$Q$1,0)*$Q$1` , where Q1 contains the interval you want to round to (i.e. `= 15 / (24*60)`).

Presuming column C contains your Y values, column D could then be a regular sequence of times with 15 minute intervals. If you have access to dynamic array formulae, column E could then be a mean of Y values for each interval: `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(FILTER(C:C,B:B=D1)),NA())`. This would return NA() if there are no results at a given interval, which should discontinue your trendline.

Hopefully that's clear and works, but let me know if I can try helping further.

[image: as described above]

Comment: Interesting idea but I think I am hoping for some kind of localised interpolation that would give the best estimates for each series base don the surrounding data..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite complex due to the fact that the data ranges and forecast ranges do not overlap entirely. In the case of given data, the forecast for 'Solar' is very uncertain because it is based on very distant data. In general, the regression method used here (the `TREND` function) gives reliable results if the data ranges and forecasts overlap, at least in large part.
As a basis, the alignment of the data with a second-degree polynomial (if possible) or a linear function in the vicinity of the forecast point was used. You can change the degree of the polynomial and the number of points as needed by modifying the formula.
The calculation formula was written as a `LAMBDA` function named `IPOL`.
Syntax
`=IPOL(raw_data, current_time)`  e.g. `=IPOL($A$2:$D$23, $F3)`
`Raw_data` – an array or range of 4 columns of data
`Current_time` – time coordinate of the forecast (reference to a cell)
Place the results in 3 columns to the right of the `Current_time`. The formula returns a single result.
You have to copy it across the entire range of results.
Formula:

```
=LAMBDA(raw_data,curr_time, LET(cx, INDEX(raw_data,,1), cy, INDEX(raw_data,,COLUMN()-COLUMN(curr_time)+1), 
row_nos, LET(list_rows, FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(raw_data)), ISNUMBER(cy)), 
rw, IFNA(XMATCH(curr_time, CHOOSEROWS(cx, list_rows), 1), XMATCH(curr_time, CHOOSEROWS(cx, list_rows), -1))+{-1;0;1}, 
CHOOSEROWS(list_rows, FILTER(rw,(rw>0)*(rw<=ROWS(list_rows))))), 
seq, SEQUENCE(,COUNT(row_nos)-1), 
TREND(CHOOSEROWS(cy,row_nos), CHOOSEROWS(cx, row_nos)^seq, curr_time^seq)))
```

[image: Interpolation]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out as well on the full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my immediate need based on a posting by zbor
on this forum: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/931160-linear-interpolation-with-unevenly-spaced-data.html

Basically, I used a formula like this with the original tabulated data in columns A and B and the new evenly spaced data in columns D and E :

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D4;$A$3:$B$675;2;FALSE);TREND(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(D4;$A$1:$A$675;1)&":B"&MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$675>D4;$A$1:$A$675));$A$1:$A$675;0));INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D4;$A$1:$A$675;1)&":A"&MATCH(MIN(IF($A$1:$A$675>D4;$A$1:$A$675));$A$1:$A$675;0));D4))

For this to work one has to sort the data to be consecutive for each series which was OK in my case as this was a once off need (for now), but one may be able to expand on this to make it more elegant. I used three different sheets for the three series and then brought the evenly spaced series together on another sheet.