Calculations with the MS excel tool using the functions and formulas in a single cell

How do we calculate Coefficient C if R/W=0.64 and H/W=1.8? using functions in a single cell/step.
Detailed query:
If We have a table with some rows and columns, How do we calculate the respective value of any input not present in that first column/row from an array?

So you can do this with linear interpolation like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75470021/4961700 and you could then weight any part as needed. If it helps then give it a vote.

Please provide your coefficient data table as a formatted text or CSV so that it can be imported into Excel. It could be done in one cell if you absolutely insist, but it would be better for you to see the scaffolding and much easier to debug! Lookup keyword "interpolation" and you should get helpful formulas to help you do this.

You just have to plug in the Bilinear Interpolation formula and use index/match to get the values of x1, x2 etc. It's straightforward although rather long and it's unfortunate that you can't use x1, x2 etc. in a Let statement because they are valid cell references. I have chosen to make the x direction correspond to columns and the y direction to rows - that means that the y-axis is going downwards, but the geometry still works. Because the x and y increments aren't constant across the whole table, I have had to do it slightly differently from @Solar Mike in the previous question.
=LET(xRange,$B$1:$D$1,
     yRange,$A$2:$A$4,
     zRange,$B$2:$D$4,
     x,F2,y,G2,
     col,XMATCH(x,xRange,-1),
      row,XMATCH(y,yRange,-1),
      x_1,INDEX(xRange,col),
      x_2,INDEX(xRange,col+1),
      y_1,INDEX(yRange,row),
      y_2,INDEX(yRange,row+1),
      f_11,INDEX(zRange,row,col),
      f_12,INDEX(zRange,row+1,col),
      f_21,INDEX(zRange,row,col+1),
      f_22,INDEX(zRange,row+1,col+1),
      (f_11*(x_2-x)*(y_2-y)+f_21*(x-x_1)*(y_2-y)+f_12*(x_2-x)*(y-y_1)+f_22*(x-x_1)*(y-y_1))/((x_2-x_1)*(y_2-y_1))
      )


